# Wrong number of files when recursively counting files in a folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, count

I'm using a simple code below to attach given UNC path as a drive and count a specific folder, and if folder count is bigger than a limit it should send an email using given settings. However there's always been difference between file details in Windows and given file count from the code below.

Any suggestions would be super nice.

```
<#
------------------------C-O-U-N-T-&-R-E-P-O-R-T----------------------- 
                                                                      #>

# Değişken tanımları

$DriveLetter = "N" #Network sürücüsü 'DriveLetter' değişkeni
$NetworkPath = "\\10.1.10.10\ebys_tmp"
$Username = "svc_userInfo"   
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "passw0rD!!" -AsPlainText -Force

$LogServer = "contoso-eposta-01"   # Uzak sunucu adı
$eventLogName = "Application"     # Event log adı
$eventLogSource = "EBYS FileCount"     # Event log kaynağı

$LogServerUsername = "contoso\svc_userinfo"  # Uzak sunucudaki kullanıcı adı
$LogServerPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Passw0rD!!" -AsPlainText -Force  # Uzak sunucudaki parola
$LogServerCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($remoteUsername, $remotePassword)

try
{

# Network Drive erişimi için 'Credential' tanımla
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $Password)

# Sürücü harfinin önceden var olup olmadığını kontrol et.
$existingDrive = Get-PSDrive -Name $DriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Sürücü harfi zaten varsa;
if ($existingDrive -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "Sürücü $DriveLetter zaten mevcut. Sayma adımına geçiliyor."
} else {
    # UNC yolunu Network sürücüsü olarak ekle
    New-PSDrive -Name $DriveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $NetworkPath -Credential $Credential -Persist
    Write-Host "Sürücü $DriveLetter başarıyla eklendi."
}

# Sürücüyü recursive olarak say, sonucu değişkene ata.
$fileCount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Exclude 'RtBackup').Count
$fileLimit = 30000

<# Uzak Sunucuda Event Log Kaydı Oluşturma
$remoteServer = "contoso-eposta-01"   # Uzak sunucu adı
$eventLogName = "Application"     # Event log adı
$eventLogSource = "EBYS FileCount"     # Event log kaynağı

$remoteUsername = "contoso.org\svc_ebystmpinfo"  # Uzak sunucudaki kullanıcı adı
$remotePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Passw0rD!!" -AsPlainText -Force  # Uzak sunucudaki parola
$remoteCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($remoteUsername, $remotePassword)
#>

if ($fileCount -ge $fileLimit)  {

# SMTP SUNUCU & EPOSTA TANIMLARI
$smtpUsername = "svc_userinfo"
$smtpPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Passw0rD!!" -AsPlainText -Force
$smtpCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($smtpUsername, $smtpPassword)

    $emailFrom = "testuser@contoso.org"
    $emailTo = "testuser2@contoso.org"
    $emailSubject = "EBYS TMP FOLDER MONITOR"
    #$emailBody = "$NetworkPath klasöründeki dosya sayısı, belirlenen $fileLimit değerini aştı. Güncel dosya sayısı: $fileCount"
    $emailBody = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width:450px;
            border: 1px solid #b3adad;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        table th {
            border: 1px solid #b3adad;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #ffbb00;
            color: #313030;
        }
        table td {
            border: 1px solid #b3adad;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #ffffff;
            color: #313030;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">CONTOSO ORG - SİSTEM SERVİSİ</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>İZİN VERİLEN MAKS. DOSYA SAYISI:</td>
                <td>$fileLimit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GÜNCEL DOSYA SAYISI:</td>
                <td>$fileCount</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">$NetworkPath klasöründeki dosya sayısı, belirlenen $fileLimit değerini aştı. Güncel dosya sayısı: $fileCount</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
"@

    # E-posta gönderme işlemiTF8
    Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Credential $smtpCredential -SmtpServer "ibb-eposta-01.ibb.net" -Body $emailBody -BodyAsHtml -Encoding UTF8
    
    }

catch
{
    Write-Host "Bir hata oluştu."
    <# Uzak Sunucuda Event Log Kaydı Oluşturma
$remoteServer = "contoso-eposta-01"   # Uzak sunucu adı
$eventLogName = "Application"     # Event log adı
$eventLogSource = "EBYS FileCount"     # Event log kaynağı

$remoteUsername = "contoso.org\svc_userinfo"  # Uzak sunucudaki kullanıcı adı
$remotePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "passwOrDHere!!" -AsPlainText -Force  # Uzak sunucudaki parola
$remoteCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($remoteUsername, $remotePassword)
#>

}

finally
{
Write-EventLog 
}

}

#
```

Hi everyone,

I'm using a simple code below to attach given UNC path as a drive and count a specific folder, and if folder count is bigger than a limit it should send an email using given settings. However there's always been difference between file details in Windows and given file count from the code below.

Comment: Am I wrong or don't you actually specify the path for your `Get-ChildItem` command? This way you use the current working directory instead of the desired network path.

Comment: Are you able to identify a file that is present in the Powershell results but not visible in Windows Explorer (or vice versa)? That might help find the root cause - for example is Windows Explorer hiding “hidden” or “system” files but Powershell including them? Is it whole folders missing or random scattered files? Does the credential used to map the drive in the script have the same permissions as the desktop user looking in Explorer? If you can find an example file the solution may present itself…

Comment: I have added the '-Path N:' to below part and it works like charm, thanks everyone && thanks @Olaf !!
# Sürücüyü recursive olarak say, sonucu değişkene ata.
$fileCount = (Get-ChildItem -Path N: -Recurse -File -Exclude 'RtBackup').Count
$fileLimit = 30000

Comment: Is a PSDrive actually needed? How about `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $NetworkPath`?

Comment: You may want to append the [-Force](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-force) switch to Get-ChildItem so you will allso count hidden and system files